# ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed. Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, networking, zscaler

I am trying to use Google Vertex AI Prediction model.
I try to predict a data point using the below code.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

project_id = "project_id"
location = "us-central1"
endpoint_id = "399999999999999999"
ai_ep_client_options = {"api_endpoint": "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"}

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "service-key.json"

instance_list = [{"feature-1":"apple", "feature-2": "banana"}]

aiplatform_client = aiplatform.gapic.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=ai_ep_client_options)
prediction_endpoint_client = aiplatform_client.endpoint_path(project=project_id, location=location, endpoint=endpoint_id)

response = aiplatform_client.predict(endpoint=prediction_endpoint_client, instances=instance_list)
```

I am getting the below error:

> _InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last) File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py:50,
> in *wrap_unary_errors..error_remapped_callable(*args,
> **kwargs)
> 49 try:
> ---> 50     return callable*(*args, **kwargs)
> 51 except grpc.RpcError as exc:
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py:1161, in
> _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.**call**(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)    1155 (    1156     state,
> 1157     call,    1158 ) = self._blocking(    1159     request,
> timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression    1160 )
> -> 1161 return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py:1004, in
> _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)    1003 else:
> -> 1004     raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
>
> _InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE     details = "failed to connect to all
> addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:142.250.31.95:443: Ssl handshake
> failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"
> debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses;
> last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:xxx.xxx.xxx.x:443: Ssl handshake failed:
> SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
> {created_time:"2023-11-03T11:03:27.2979758+00:00", grpc_status:14}"
>
> > 
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[18], line 16
> 13 aiplatform_client = aiplatform.gapic.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=ai_ep_client_options)
> 14 prediction_endpoint_client = aiplatform_client.endpoint_path(project=project_id, location=location,
> endpoint=endpoint_id)
> ---> 16 response = aiplatform_client.predict(endpoint=prediction_endpoint_client,
> instances=instance_list)
> 17 response
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\google\cloud\aiplatform_v1\services\prediction_service\client.py:602,
> in PredictionServiceClient.predict(self, request, endpoint, instances,
> parameters, retry, timeout, metadata)
> 597 metadata = tuple(metadata) + (
> 598     gapic_v1.routing_header.to_grpc_metadata((("endpoint", request.endpoint),)),
> 599 )
> 601 # Send the request.
> --> 602 response = rpc(
> 603     request,
> 604     retry=retry,
> 605     timeout=timeout,
> 606     metadata=metadata,
> 607 )
> 609 # Done; return the response.
> 610 return response
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py:154,
> in _GapicCallable.**call**(self, timeout, retry, *args, **kwargs)
> 151     metadata.extend(self._metadata)
> 152     kwargs["metadata"] = metadata
> --> 154 return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py:52,
> in *wrap_unary_errors..error_remapped_callable(*args,
> **kwargs)
> 50     return callable*(*args, **kwargs)
> 51 except grpc.RpcError as exc:
> ---> 52     raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
>
> ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last
> error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:xxx.xx.xx.xx:443: Ssl handshake failed:
> SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

I am running this on "Windos" OS.

```
aiplatform.__version__
```

returns **1.28.1**.

I am running this code on my corporate machine. This code used to run successfully few days ago. But there are some security updates done on the systems and since then this error started coming up.
I only a ML/Python expert, and i dont know the basics of Networking, security certs, CA files, .pem files etc..,

In my research, I have seen some solutions to similar problems, but they were mostly on Linux/Unix systems. Suggest some solutions on Windows.

I am not sure if this is a Networking/Security related Issue or a GCP Python Vertex AI Issue. Kindly excuse if the tags are ir-relevant.

Comment: I can't help you on that windows environment issue. But, as generic answer, I can only recommend to use a linux based environment: WSL2  on Windows OS, MacOS, or Linux. One of my developers had issues with windows and we set up a Workstation VM to solve the issue (based on Linux of course). You could also use VertexAI workbench (jupyter notebook) to run your code. In addition, for security purpose, never ever use a service account key file for authentication!

Comment: Thank you for the response. As a backup, currently i am using Vertex AI workbench for my predictions. 
Regarding the service account key, we dont use it in prod, this was only dev . hence the file.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is Firewall. Since you mentioned that there was a security update prior the issue, it might have reconfigured your network firewall blocking the connection to your Vertex AI service.

Troubleshoot your network connection to ensure that its not intercepting or modifying your SSL handshake, at the same time, check you machine's certificate and make sure it is still valid and has not expired.

Refer to this document to use [Private Service Connect to access Vertex AI online predictions from on-premises](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/vertex-psc-googleapis).

You can also reach out to [Vertex AI support](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/support/getting-support) for detailed assistance.